# Custom Default Effect in Monogame Content Pipeline

Tags: xna, monogame

So I ended up writing my first HLSL Shader for MonoGame, and managed to somehow connect it to a Model I want to draw.
So far so good.
However the "somehow managed to do it code" is in my opinion ugly, and probably not the Intended way to achieve this:

```cs
internal Model(ContentManager content)
{
    mModel = content.Load<Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Model>("models/CustomModel");
    // individual effect for individual models
    var effect = content.Load<Effect>("effects/CustomEffect").Clone();
    effect.Parameters["Texture"].SetValue(mModel.Meshes[0].MeshParts[0].Effect.Parameters["Texture"].GetValueTexture2D());

    foreach (var mesh in mModel.Meshes)
    {
        foreach (var meshPart in mesh.MeshParts)
        {
            meshPart.Effect = effect;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I load in my Model and the effect individually and replace all the BasicEffects of the model with my newly loaded custom effect. And keep the old TextureVariable.

I'm for myself convinced that there's a more elegant solution to this, a solution that involves telling MonoGame to use CustomEffect instead of BasicEffect.
I know that using the MGCB Tool I can specify a DefaultEffect for the ModelProcessor, however I haven't found out what I need to do so I can specify my effect there without the Game crashing and telling me that effects/CustomEffect isn't a valid effect.

So is there a better way to achieve the same goal my existing code does? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is the primary one available, and the most flexible.

You do need to move the effect clone and parameter lines inside the foreach loop and change it to:

```
var effect = content.Load<Effect>("effects/CustomEffect").Clone();
effect.Parameters["Texture"].SetValue(meshPart.Effect.Parameters["Texture"].GetValueTexture2D());
```

Otherwise all parts of the model will use the same texture.

The lack of elegance is in the fact that this is a direct carry-over from the `XNA` platform.

The other option is to make your parameters and semantics match those of `BasicEffect`, at which point you *should* be able to set it in the Model Processor. The model processor expects the parameters exist and in that specific order.

Comment: For it to work with the model processor: Do I need to create an extra wrapper class or something, or is adding uniform variables to the effect enough?

Comment: No extra classes needed. Make sure your uniform variables and semantics align with `BasicEffect` That should be enough.  I have never tried it. From the code base this should work.

Comment: Do I simply provide the path inside the content folder, or just the basename, without the extension?

Comment: Great question, I am unable to give a definitive answer at this time(I have to leave in a few minutes for an appointment), If I were to venture a guess, the full content path, since the order of compilation requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like every `effect` has the same value, because it doesn't change in the for-loop.

So I think you can also define the `effect` in the `meshPart` instead. so you don't have to go through the for-loop for each individual one.

You can also create the effect in the `Loadcontent` class in game1.cs, so you don't have to define it each time again.

I think that's it as far as I know.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "define the effect in the meshPart instead"? Also it doesn't matter where I create the effect

Comment: This is assuming that `meshPart` is a custom class where you can create other variables inside of it. But looking back at it, I'm not sure if it really helps in performance regardless. Maybe since this question does not specify a problem, then this question can also (if not better) be asked on Code Review: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `meshPart` is a built-in class that contains the vertex list of the triangles and the effect used to render them. Without the `.Clone()`, all of the effects would share the `uniform` parameters like textures.